# canvas - how to set css for image inside canvas

Tags: css, angular, canvas, fabricjs

team,

I have canvas where I can able to upload multiple image but my css is reflecting only for main canvas

but I am trying for images which is inside the canvas.

Here is my html code

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6">
<div class="canvas-container" (drop)="handleDropOnCanvas($event)" (dragover)="handleDragOverCanvas($event)">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

File upload html code

```
    <div class="panel panel-default panel-upload">
  <div class="panel-heading">Upload Picture</div>
  <div class="panel-body text-center">
    <img id="testImage"  (dragover)="false"(dragend)="false"
    (drop)="handleDrop($event)" class="images-item-upload" *ngFor='let url of urls' [src]="url?.url"  (click)="addImageOnCanvas(url.url);"/>
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-block file-container">
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-upload"></i> Choose a file
      <input type='file' [disabled]="urls.length >= 16"  multiple (change)="readUrl($event);">
    </label>

  </div>
</div>
```

With this html code where i was able to see images inisde the one canvas

ts code

```
    readUrl(event): void {
    let files = event.target.files;
    if (files) {
        for (let file of files) {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e: any) => {
                this.urls.push({
                    url: e.target.result,
                    isClicked: false
                });
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }

}
```

with my current code i was not getting how to set css for the images if i apply css it is applying for canvas not for image.

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot be applied to images drawn on a canvas because css is only for objects that exist in the DOM. The purpose of canvas is to provide an efficient system for drawing and manipulating pixels without needing to account for objects in the DOM space.

The benefit of using FabricJS is that the you can handle objects in a canvas similarly to how you would DOM objects (without a framework like FabricJS, the canvas is just a blank slate that has no knowledge of what has been drawn there).

To add style customizations to a FabricJS object you need to use the available FabricJS image properties. See http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html for all properties.